# numpy slicing screws image colors (werid)

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, colors, numpy-ndarray

I have an RGB image as an ndarray

```
print(img.shape)
>>> (64, 64, 3)
```

I want to store a bunch of images into another ndarray:

```
batch = np.empty((64, 64, 3, 2))
batch[...,0] = img
```

Now if I do

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

everything is looks fine. But if I do

```
plt.imshow(batch[...,0])
```

the colors are messed up! It looks inverted or maybe the channels are mixed up. What's going on?

Comment: Use `batch = np.empty((64, 64, 3, 2),dtype=np.uint8)`? Or `dtype = img.dtype`?

Comment: @Diviakar's comment is the answer. By default `numpy.empty` creates an array of floating point values, and `plt.imshow` treats integer and floating point arrays differently. Specifically, `imshow` expects floating point arrays to have values that are between 0.0 and 1.0, so (0.0, 0.0, 1.0) is blue, (0.5, 0.5, 0.5) is middle gray, etc.